# Is it possible to do approximate regex (fuzzy) matching with vala using libtre5?

Tags: regex, vala

I'm wondering if it is possible to do approximate Regex matching with Vala using some library.

I have found that ubuntu provides libtre5, but i don't know if i can use that using vala. Otherwise is there a GLib thing do to that ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create bindings for libtre5 to use it from Vala.  If someone had already done this it would, in theory, be included in the [list of bindings](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ListOfBindings) maintained on Vala's wiki.

As for other regex libraries, glib includes support for PCRE; see [GLib.Regex](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Regex.html) and friends.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i was not aware of "binding" a library for vala usage. As for PCRE, it does not include fuzzy matching sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I'm a vala noob even though I really do love this language, binding library for vala usage is not part of my skills, so I ended up using simple implementation of **Damerau-Levenshtein** algorithm I adapted :

```
/**
 * This implementation is an adaptation based on Kevin L. Stern's work
 * https://github.com/KevinStern/software-and-algorithms
 *
 * It is full implementation of Damerau-Levenshtein algorithm
 *
 */
public static int compute_damerau_levenshtein_distance (string source, string target,
  int insertCost = 1, int deleteCost = 1, int replaceCost = 1, int swapCost = 1)
{
  int deleteDistance = 0;
  int insertDistance = 0;
  int matchDistance = 0;
  int jSwap = 0;
  int maxSourceLetterMatchIndex = 0;
  int? candidateSwapIndex = 0;
  int swapDistance = 0;

  if (source.length == 0)
  {
    return target.length * insertCost;
  }
  if (target.length == 0)
  {
    return source.length * deleteCost;
  }

  int[,] table = new int[source.length, target.length];
  Gee.HashMap<char, int> sourceIndexByCharacter = new Gee.HashMap<char, int> ();

  if (source[0] != target[0])
    table[0, 0] = (int)Math.fmin(replaceCost, deleteCost + insertCost);

  sourceIndexByCharacter.set (source[0], 0);

  for (int i = 1; i < source.length; i++)
  {
    deleteDistance = table[i - 1, 0] + deleteCost;
    insertDistance = (i + 1) * deleteCost + insertCost;
    matchDistance = i * deleteCost + (source[i] == target[0] ? 0 : replaceCost);
    table[i, 0] = (int)Math.fmin(Math.fmin(deleteDistance, insertDistance), matchDistance);
  }

  for (int j = 1; j < target.length; j++)
  {
    deleteDistance = (j + 1) * insertCost + deleteCost;
    insertDistance = table[0, j - 1] + insertCost;
    matchDistance = j * insertCost + (source[0] == target[j] ? 0 : replaceCost);
    table[0, j] = (int)Math.fmin(Math.fmin(deleteDistance, insertDistance), matchDistance);
  }

  for (int i = 1; i < source.length; i++)
  {
    maxSourceLetterMatchIndex = source[i] == target[0] ? 0 : -1;
    for (int j = 1; j < target.length; j++)
    {
      candidateSwapIndex = sourceIndexByCharacter.get (target[j]);
      jSwap = maxSourceLetterMatchIndex;
      deleteDistance = table[i - 1, j] + deleteCost;
      insertDistance = table[i, j - 1] + insertCost;
      matchDistance = table[i - 1, j - 1];

      if (source[i] != target[j])
        matchDistance += replaceCost;
      else
        maxSourceLetterMatchIndex = j;

      if (candidateSwapIndex != null && jSwap != -1)
      {
        int iSwap = candidateSwapIndex;
        int preSwapCost;
        if (iSwap == 0 && jSwap == 0)
          preSwapCost = 0;
        else
          preSwapCost = table[(int)Math.fmax(0, iSwap - 1), (int)Math.fmax(0, jSwap - 1)];
        swapDistance = preSwapCost + (i - iSwap - 1) * deleteCost + (j - jSwap - 1) * insertCost + swapCost;
      }
      else
        swapDistance = int.MAX;
      table[i, j] = (int)Math.fmin(Math.fmin(Math.fmin(deleteDistance, insertDistance), matchDistance), swapDistance);
    }
    sourceIndexByCharacter.set (source[i], i);
  }
  return table[source.length - 1, target.length - 1];
}
```